# Using ProgressBar in Java Lanterna

Tags: java, progress-bar, lanterna

I tried to use ProgressBar as below:

```
    ProgressBar Prog=new ProgressBar(0,100,50);
    Prog.setValue(0)
    //
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    String line = bf.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
                lines.add(line);
                Prog.setValue((int)(100*(double)lines.size()/MaxLen)); //ProgressBar  will ot be updated
      
                line = bf.readLine();

        }
            bf.close();
```

I also tried this method:

```
 ProgressBar.DefaultProgressBarRenderer DP=new ProgressBar.DefaultProgressBarRenderer();
 DP.drawComponent((TextGUIGraphics)gui.getScreen().newTextGraphics(),Prog  );
```

GUI is MultiWindowTextGUI belong to contex, but it does not work because of Cast Problem:

```
 com.googlecode.lanterna.screen.AbstractScreen$1 cannot be cast to com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.TextGUIGraphics
```

Edit2:in component aproach,  it need this:

```
Prog.setRenderer(new ProgressBar.DefaultProgressBarRenderer());
```

and a timer:

```
   Timer timer = new Timer("ProgressBar-timer", true);
         timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                //Do some thing
             }
         }, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you wanted to draw a progress-bar on the screen somehow.

#### Issue

But `gui.getScreen().newTextGraphics()` is giving [`TextGraphics`](https://mabe02.github.io/lanterna/apidocs/3.0/com/googlecode/lanterna/screen/AbstractScreen.html#newTextGraphics--) and not desired `TextGUIGraphics`.

#### Draw on the screen

Given your `renderer`, you can use it to draw the `progressBar` on your screen.

Therefore, use the renderer's method [`drawComponent(TextGUIGraphics graphics, ProgressBar component)`](https://mabe02.github.io/lanterna/apidocs/3.0/com/googlecode/lanterna/gui2/ProgressBar.DefaultProgressBarRenderer.html#drawComponent-com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.TextGUIGraphics-com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.ProgressBar-):

```
// Given
MultiWindowTextGUI textGui = createGuiOn(screen);
TextGraphics textGraphics = screen.newTextGraphics();

// What you need, but don't get
TextGUIGraphics graphics = null;  // WARNING: There is no method to get the graphics object from!

// Then
renderer.drawComponent( graphics, progressBar );
```

The drawing is a low-level rendering action. See [Tutorial 3](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/blob/master/docs/tutorial/Tutorial03.md).

And there seems neither a constructor, nor a public method, that gives you that `TextGUIGraphics`, see the [search on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/search?p=5&q=public%20TextGUIGraphics).

Instead consider to work with components like `ProgressBar`.

#### Work with components

[`ProgressBar`](https://mabe02.github.io/lanterna/apidocs/3.0/com/googlecode/lanterna/gui2/ProgressBar.html) is a **component**. So you can add it simply to your TextGUI:

```
final Window window = new BasicWindow("My Root Window");  // create window
window.setComponent(progressBar);  // set component of window

textGUI.addWindowAndWait(window);  // add window to gui
```

See [Tutorial 4](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/blob/master/docs/tutorial/Tutorial04.md) for working with components.

Comment: with TextGUIGraphics graphics = null  , i got NullPointerException Error:

Comment: @Ddll If you read my answer, I explain why you are not supposed to use `TextGUIGraphics` from outside. Instead work with components.

Comment: Actually, I added ProgressBar as a component, but inside the loop, its value is not updated and there is no example in  Tutorial 4  for working with ProgressBar

Comment: Resolved with a few changes